# In Angular using Observable to respond to an api request and then push any changes to the controller

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs5

I'm currently using angular 5, but this is more just a general RxJs question. I want to be able to respond to a controller's request for an api's data with the data, but then also push changes anytime the value becomes stale. I'm currently trying to achieve this using multicasting, but that doesn't seem right since only the initial value is received.

```
export class EditorService {
  private getSubject = new Subject<null>();

  onLanguageChange() {
    // currentLanguage is a model so will be updated by angular
    this.getSubject.next();
  }

  get(): Observable<DeltaStatic> {
    const get = () => {
      return this.http.get<BackEndResponse<MasterBlob<DeltaStatic|string>>>(
        `${backendEndPoint}/get-all`,
      ).pipe(
        map(blob => blob.data[this.currentLanguage][this.currentKey].quillBlob)
      );
    };

    return get().pipe(
      multicast(this.getSubject),
      refCount(),
      switchMap(get),
    );
  }
}
```

The other option, which feels slightly more idiomatic, is to just use a subject with switchMap, but I don't want to have to trigger next from the controller to get the first value after I subscribe:

```
export class EditorService {
  private getSubject = new Subject<null>();

  onLanguageChange() {
    // currentLanguage is a model so will be updated by angular
    this.getSubject.next();
  }

  get(): Observable<DeltaStatic> {
    const get = () => {
      return this.http.get<BackEndResponse<MasterBlob<DeltaStatic|string>>>(
        `${backendEndPoint}/get-all`,
      ).pipe(
        map(blob => blob.data[this.currentLanguage][this.currentKey].quillBlob)
      );
    };

    return this.getSubject.pipe(
      switchMap(get),
    );
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'editor',
  templateUrl: './editor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./editor.component.scss']
})
export class EditorComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(private editorService: EditorService) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.editorService.get().subscribe(data => {...});
    this.editorService.getSubject.next();
  }
}
```

Finally I toyed with my go to solution of using a ReplaySubject, but that requires me to subscribe to the initial Observable in the service which goes against the best practice of waiting to make the call until the controller needs something and calls subscribe. I also feel like I always just resort to ReplaySubject since it is the most hackable, but there has to be a better way to achieve this.

Comment: Do you want the data to be shared across subscribers? Or should each new subscription trigger a fresh request in any case?

Comment: Each new subscription would trigger a new call. I think a I would prefer to implement a caching layer at a higher level.

Comment: And the handling for staleness... Should each subscription get its own request when that happens as well? Or should that share a single request broadcasted to all subscribers?

Comment: A single request broadcasted to all subscribers, although since that sort of conflict with the idea above of each new subscription triggering a new call I could go either way on that one. Whichever is cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution if you want to not share data between subscribers at all. It's mostly like the one you had, it just uses `startWith` to trigger the initial request immediately, avoiding the problem you mentioned:

```js
export class EditorService {

  private languageChange$ = new Subject<void>();

  public onLanguageChange() {
    this.languageChange$.next();
  }

  public get(): Observable<DeltaStatic> {
    // By appending startWith(), which is short for startWith(undefined),
    // we ensure that we trigger the request once initially.
    return this.languageChange$
        .startWith(undefined)
        .switchMap(() => this.requestData());
  }

  private requestData() {
    return this.http.get<BackEndResponse<MasterBlob<DeltaStatic|string>>>(`${backendEndPoint}/get-all`)
      .pipe(
        map(blob => blob.data[this.currentLanguage][this.currentKey].quillBlob)
      );
  }

}
```

If you want the refreshed data to be shared across subscribers, you can probably do this, although I didn't test it:

```js
export class EditorService {

  private refreshed$ = new Subject<DeltaStatic>();

  public onLanguageChange() {
    this.requestData().subscribe(data => this.refreshed$.next(data));
  }

  public get(): Observable<DeltaStatic> {
    // Trigger request immediately, then concat any future updates
    // to it.
    return this.requestData().concat(this.refreshed$);
  }

  private requestData() {
    return this.http.get<BackEndResponse<MasterBlob<DeltaStatic|string>>>(`${backendEndPoint}/get-all`)
      .pipe(
        map(blob => blob.data[this.currentLanguage][this.currentKey].quillBlob)
      );
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for you response, checking out the second code block now, but I wasn't able to get the first one working. I made this simple plunker as an example https://plnkr.co/edit/knOv2dR1gHGDsJjipqoH?p=preview

Comment: @CodySchaaf If you pass `startWith(undefined)` (or anything else) explicitly, it works: https://plnkr.co/edit/D4Kwx2SfImz87IPe9mlg?p=preview I've updated my answer

Comment: These are great, thanks a bunch! Although I like how switchMap allows you to delegate all api calls through it, I think your second example is even clearer and more performant and works as expected. I really appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome. Just to stress this, the two solutions do different things. In the second example if the request fails, all subscribers error out.